# Precedence for pointing to operator

Tags: c, structure

What is the precedence level of `pointing to ->` operator wrt to the arthmetic, bitwise and other pointer referencing operators such as `&`.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence

Comment: "operator precedence in C" gives me quite good search results. What do you miss?

Comment: It's also easy to write tests for precedence.

Comment: @JensGustedt the confusion was with the table from Wikipedia. Would like to thank all for the sorting it out for me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"High". See the [operator precedence table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence). Note that the linked-to table includes C++ too, so you need to read it carefully.

[Here's another table](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/C/CONCEPT/precedence.html), which is C only. You can see that the only operators that share the precedence level of `->` are `()` (function call), `[]` (array indexing) and `.` (element selection).

Answer (score 1):

It shares the high(est) precedence in 'C'. Precedence of -> is higher than &.

You can refer to the precedence table [here](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/c/c-precedence.html)(C Table) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence) (Wiki - includes C++)

Comment: It *shares* the highest precedence.

Comment: I put the 'est' in braces to indicate the same. But, since you mentioned it, I have modified my answer too. : )

Answer (score 1):

As a postfix operator, `->` has the highest level of precedence (along with the `.` member selection operator, postfix `++` and `--`, `[]`, and function call `()`).  So an expression like `&foo->bar` is interpreted as `&(foo->bar)`.

If you have multiple operators with the same precedence, they evaluate left-to-right.  For example, `[]` and `()` are also postfix operators, so `a[i]->b` is interpreted as `(a[i])->b` and `f()->m` is interpreted as `(f())->m`, `p++->q` is interpreted as `(p++)->q`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

-> has the highest precedence level in C.
 check the [precedence chart](http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html) for further info.